# CollapsingToolbarLayout with Image, fixed aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout

I have a image inside CollapsingToolbarLayout (just the same as the example https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare).

However, I want to fixed the aspect ratio of the backdrop as 16:9.

I tried setting the `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, updating the `LayoutParams` in code, but it does not work.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by putting the ImageView inside a PercentRelativeLayout.